# Bean instance is not getting loaded

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I need a help regarding dependency injection.

I hava a bean class which is having a object reference of JdbcTemplate and I am using `@Autowired` to 
create instance of that object. But that object is not getting loaded and as a result NullPointerException is thrown 
from setCustName() method.

Please help

Bean Class :

```
class CustomerBean {

    private String custName;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setCustName(String custName) {
    this.custName = custName;
    jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<bean id="myjdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>  

 <bean id="custBean" class="com.test.CustomerBean">
        <property name="custName" value="John" />
 </bean>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'custName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
```

Comment: How, somewhere else in your code, are you getting an instance of `CustomerBean`? Are you doing `new CustomerBean()` somewhere? Then it will not work - you'll need to let Spring manage creation of Spring beans, Spring cannot automatically inject dependencies on objects that you instantiate yourself using `new`.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks for your reply. I am not creating instance of `CustomerBean` anywhere else

Comment: But somewhere in your code you must be getting an instance of `CustomerBean` on which you call the `setCustName` method. Where does that code get the instance of `CustomerBean` from?

Comment: Could you post your full stacktrace please?

Comment: @GergelyBacso Added

Comment: The full stacktrace is needed to see the call hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get NullPointerException  as jdbcTemplate is null / not injected.

if you describe bean custBean by xml , as you did, you should add :
< property name="jdbcTemplate" value="myjdbcTemplate" /> for inject jdbcTemplate into your bean.

you have mixed configuration - xml and annotation. in your xml should be :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package....." />
```

to support @Autowired and CustomerBean should be @service or @component.

---

**vaiant1 :**

add  into xml and

```
@Component
class CustomerBean {

    private String custName;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setCustName(String custName) {
        this.custName = custName;
        jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    }
}
```

**variant2 :**

class CustomerBean {

```
private String custName;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
     this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public void setCustName(String custName) {
   this.custName = custName;
   jdbcTemplate.update(query);
}
```

}

and xml

```
 <bean id="custBean" class="com.test.CustomerBean">
        <property name="custName" value="John" />
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="myjdbcTemplate" />
 </bean>
```

Comment: Why should I add `<property>` for `jdbcTemplate` as I am using `@Autowired ` ?

Comment: 1. do you have context:component-scan? 2.custBean is not component for autoscan as there is not annotation @component/@service . 3 you configure your been by xml , there is no @Autowired for this. you mixed configuration. create/describe been by  xml or with annotation

Comment: try to debug and you will see exception in method setCustName in call jdbcTemplate.update(query);

Answer (score 1):

1. Add @Component annotation to the bean class which contains beans that can be autowired.
2. After adding the above @Component annotation on beans, we need to tell spring to scan these respective beans and load all the autowired dependencies. This can be done by declaring the following XMLconfiguration

   `<context:component-scan base-packages="<your_package_names>"/>`

   for example if my package structure is com.mycompany

   `<context:component-scan base-packages="com.mycompany"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `<context:annotation-config>` which enables the usage of different annotations in bean classes.

Also I strongly recommend against usage of different dependencies in properties setters. In your code sample you assume that the jdbcTemplate was autowired before the call of the setter, fact that you cannot be sure of.

Therefore the logic that you placed in the setter, regarding the jdbc template would be more properly placed in a method annotated with @PostConstruct.